Exists a way to add rows to a DataVerse Table in Power Automate Desktop using variables?
Good Day,   Because of Project needs I need to use the connector "add a new row to the selected environment" in a dataverse table and need to fill the environment and table name with variables instead of  Fixed Names.  Unfortunately I have a "Dynamic Schema couldnt be Retrieved". Does somebody know a way I can  add a row to a dataverse table using variables? 

This looks like Power Automate Azure, not Power Automate Desktop.
